# (NotePad++) Remove Lines which are only "Numbers" (or Symbols or A-z)

Tags: notepad++

For example in this list:

```
abcdefg
1234567890
@#$%^*!@
asjdkclc1234
akjsocj!@$
skoekc!@32
13466!#%
```

I just want to remove the first three lines and keep the others.

Comment: You highlight them then press delete. What does this have to do with programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for an automatic solution (in case the lines are somewhere in a huge file), here is a regular expression search/replace:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `^([[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:]]+|[@#$%^*!@]+)\R`
- **Replace With** (leave empty)
- check **Regular expression**
- click **Replace All**

The Search looks for *something* that:

- makes up the whole line (`^` is start of line and `\R` is the newline at the end)
- and consists of either

  - only characters
  - only digits
  - only the symbols in the third alternative
- the three alternatives are divided by the `|`
- by including the `\R` it removes also the line itself

Comment: Just a bit nitpicking - you have two times `@` in your last character class, this isn't wrong, just unnecessary. Besides that, I left an upvote.

Comment: WOW! Thanks Man :)